# How to get data from jQuery to PHP into a MVC Pattern

Tags: php, jquery, json

I need to know if I can pass data from index.php to another page (like json.php) and then retrieve this data in PHP to modify the objects of the controller or the database.

I have attempted several options, but none work. I haven't read anything about that I want and I think it isn't available because all that I must implement is around index.php and the controller cannot receive data elsewhere. But maybe someone knows an alternative way.

I don't want to paste all my scripts I just leave above three that can be useful to show what I want.

Mainly I want to use buttons or user-inputs with some values and then I want to pass them to AJAX via json.php, but I need to do more things between reception's and response's server like update database, insert new items, etc.

I have the following files:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css">
    <script 
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src='./js/main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require_once './php/model/warehouse.php';
    require_once './php/model/cart.php';
    require_once './php/model/customers.php';
    //require_once './php/util/json.php';
    $shop = Shop::get_instance();
    $shop->load_articles();
    ...
    $cart= Cart::getInstance();
    $cart->load_cart();
    ...
    $costumers = Custemers::get_instance();
    $costumers->load_costumers();
    ...
    <div id='btn-addtocart-index'>add to cart</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js/main.js**

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#btn-addtocart-index').click(function () {
        var str = {prod_id: 1, quantity: 1, increment: 3, type: 'modify'}
        str = JSON.stringify(str)
        $.ajax({
            data: str,
            url: './php/util/json.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            ContentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(resp){
                alert("TYPE:\t\t" + resp.type + "\nPRODID:\t" + resp.prod_id +"\nQUANT:\t\t"+resp.quantity + "\nINC:\t\t" + resp.increment);
            }
        })
    })
)
```

**php/util/json.php**

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
if (isset($GLOBALS['customers'])) {
    echo "<br><br>CUSTOMERS<br>";
    foreach($customers as $customer) {
        print_r($customer->get_data());
        echo '<br>';
    }

}
header("Content-type: text/json; charset=utf-8");
if($content) {
    global $shop;
    $json = json_decode($content);
    $GLOBALS['json'] = $json;
    //echo 'obj json->type: ' . $json->type;
    if (isset($GLOBALS['customers'])) {
        echo "RIGHT NOW?";
        $customers[0]->get_data();
    }

} else {
    //echo '#mem: \'' . file_get_contents('php://memory') . '\'';
}
echo "$content";
?>
```

Comment: Big answer sir @keyboardSmasher! These files are only to test my future web. I don't need your discouragement words. Thanks!

Comment: Remember you was also a beginner some time ago.

Comment: `all that I must implement is around index.php and the controller cannot receive data elsewhere` ... So...  `$_POST` doesn't work in your controller?  AS a super global it should be accessible everywhere.  Many MVC frameworks use a wrapper around `$_POST` for example in Code Igniter, you can do `$this->input->post('foo')` which is basically `$_POST['foo']` with some basic isset checks etc...  All wrapped up in the `CI_Input` class etc... etc..  An "AJAX" request is nothing magical it's treated as a Post or Get by the server regardless of how it was done.